# Why it appears the erro Non-static method should not be called statically in this context?

Tags: laravel

Im trying to use this package " dannyvankooten/laravel-vat" to load a select menu with the countries and then validate the vat number inserted in the input type text.

So I have this in a form:

```
<div class="form-group font-size-sm">
    <select class="form-control" name="country" id="country">
        @foreach($countries as $country)
            <option value="{{$country}}">{{$country}}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group font-size-sm">
    <label for="vat" class="text-gray">VAT</label>
    <input type="text" id="vat" name="vat" class="form-control" value="">
</div>
```

In the RegistrationController I have in a method this to return the $countries to the view to the select menu:

```
$countries = Countries::all();
```

But it appears:

```
Non-static method DvK\Laravel\Vat\Countries::all() should not be called statically
```

Do you know why?

Comment: Could be because it's not a static method? Have you tried to create a new Countries object ($countries = new Countries();) and then use $countries->all() ?

Comment: You probably wanted to use the facade `DvK\Laravel\Vat\Facades\Countries`, which extends the laravel facade and provies the static accessors like `all()` ... but accidentally imported `DvK\Laravel\Vat\Countries` ... just a guess though ... but thats usually the laravel-style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your specific case (laravel & facades), it's because you have imported the wrong class in your controller.

You need to replace

```
use DvK\Laravel\Vat\Countries;
```

with

```
use DvK\Laravel\Vat\Facades\Countries;
```

like shown in the readme @ https://github.com/dannyvankooten/laravel-vat

The facade is what provides the static accessor e.g. `Countries::all()`

Answer (score 1):

`all` is not a static method in the `Countries` class. You should first create an instance of `Countries` and then call its `all` method:

```
$countries = new Countries();
$allCountries = $countries->all();

return view('congress.registration', ['countries' => $allCountries]);
```

Comment: Thanks, but it returns "Countries {#255}". Do you know why? In the select menu no country appears.

Comment: Can you show your controller code? I'll take a look

Comment: Thanks, I have that code $countries = new Countries(); $countries->all() and then $countries is returned "return view('congress.registration',
                ['countries' => $countries ]);".

Comment: Where are you seeing `Countries {#255}`?

Comment: he's seeing the #255 (number of elements), because he passes $countries to the view instead of $countries->all()

Comment: Ah yes, well spotted!